# How to turn createReadStream into buffer in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, fs

I’m using GraphQL upload and do the following:

{ createReadStream } = await file;

How do I turn this createReadStream into a buffer variable that I can pass to another function?

Comment: What is your `file` variable? There's not enough info in this question for anyone to answer.  `createReadStream()` is a function that returns a stream.  If you just want to read a file into a Buffer, then use `fs.readFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
const stream = createReadStream();
```

Then turned converted the stream into a buffer and passed that to my function.